# SSIS 2008 Understanding Rows Per batch and Maximum insert commit size

Tags: ssis, oledb, dataflow

I'm trying to understand these two options in a OLE DB Destination in a Dataflow Task.

From what i have understood :

- MICS : means the max number of rows before a commit
- RPB  : I didnt really understand this one..

Anyway i have this dataflow task :
Oracle 10 => SQL SERVER 2008

And here is my tests :

When i put a 0 in MICS , i have the result expected, which is only one commit at the end.
When i put a 1000 in MICS , i have a commit every 6709 rows, **which is definilety not what i expected**
After a few tests, whatever the number chosen, there is always one to commit every 6709 rows.

I'm starting to think this has to do with other properties that i have'nt heard of.

Any expert on the subject  ?

If you do not understand my problem or need more information, please ask so i can edit my question

Comment: Do you use fast load at the destination?

Comment: Yes i am , i think these two properties are enabled only in fast load

Comment: See [also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26302693/181965)